# Linux Bash Script for calculating average of multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a scipt which will take parameter of the folder which it will do the job. The aim is to calculate average number of reviews and print the result next to the name of the file. I wrote the script for only one file it works okay but I couldn't find any solutions to do it on multiple files. I should get an output like ;

```
    % ./averagereviews.sh path_to_folder
    hotel_11212 3.51
    hotel_2121 2.62
    hotel_31212 2.43
```

...

I done this task for only one hotel and the code is like this;

```
    grep "<Overall>" $1 | sed 's/<Overall>//g'| awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/NR}'
```

This simply searches the word "" in the file and gets the number next to it, then adds these numbers and divides the sum with NR to find average.

when I run it the output is the average value for the given hotel

```
    ./averagereviews.sh  hotel_190158.dat
    4.00578
```

But I should do this to multiple .dat files in a folder with printing the name of hotel. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could "cheat"

```
 > cat averagereviews.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 SUM=0
 data_files=$(ls $1/dataFile*.dat)
 cat $data_files | grep "<Overall>" | sed -e 's/<Overall>//g' | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/NR}'
```

and run (from wherever, with whichever paths you need)

```
> ~/tools/averagereviews.sh /tmp/data/
```

Simply, I'm `cat`ing all the files first, and apply your command to the rest - having it behave like the pipe is a single file.

Comment: But I should achieve it outside of the folder. For example I am in my home folder right now and the folder which contains all data is in data_folder and also my script is in home folder, same level with data_folder. Also my script should take the folder name as parameter. So when I write ./averagereviews.sh folder_name it should find mean for each data file in that folder.

Comment: Then I suppose you have a method of finding the files that are "data files". Something like "their name is data_###.txt". I updated my answer to take your comment into account.

Comment: Actually I couldn't understand how could you cat data_files. Its a directory so it gives error you can't cat to a directory. Maybe its my mistake I couldn't explain correctly. Now I am in a file called work and I have my script and also a folder called "data_files" in it. When I run my script it should take all data files (eg dataFile1.dat) and using the information inside data files take average for all of the data files. The average is for each data.

Comment: I wrote the `find` call for that. If your "data_files" folder only contains your data files, you could simply replace my `data_files=$(find $1 -name "data*")` with `data_files=$(ls $1/dataFile*.dat)`.

Comment: I did it but it stills gives me the error "cat: data_files: Is a directory"

Comment: I forgot the `$` in `cat $data_files`. I updated my answer, this should work.

Comment: Yeah that worked without any problem but it printed the total average for all the dat files. My aim is to find average results for each dat files. I have like hundereds of dat files and inside each dat file there are some numbers which I calculate average of them. From my understanding this script that you helped me to write now finds the average result for all dat files not individually for each dat file.